# Reverse proxy 502 bad gateway

Tags: centos, nginx, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I have setup a subdomain to proxy my plesk panel, but when saving pages I am getting `502 Bad Gateway` error instead of a completion message. I am running `CentOS 6`.

Here is my `vhost.conf` configuration for `http://plesk.domain.tld/`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule $ https://plesk.domain.tld/ [R,L]
```

Here is my `vhost_ssl.conf` configuration for `https://plesk.domain.tld/`:

```
SSLProxyEngine On

<Location />
    ProxyPass https://localhost:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:8443/
</Location>
```

I have more than enough (and I have even checked) RAM, CPU and HDD. There are no spikes. As well, the posted information does save, it just errors when trying to show me a "This information has been saved." green/red block.

Here is the relevent error from `/var/log/nginx/error.log` (IP/Host Filtered):

> 2014/05/29 02:42:41 [error] 8046#0: *402 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 173.238.XX.XX, server: plesk.domain.tld, request: "POST /smb/web/edit HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://198.100.XX.XX:7081/smb/web/edit", host: "plesk.domain.tld", referrer: "https://plesk.domain.tld/smb/web/edit"

Comment: Any relevant error in `plesk` side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested in the solution, here it is:

Additional directives for HTTP:

```
SSLProxyEngine Off
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule $ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Additional directives for HTTPS:

```
SSLProxyEngine On
AllowEncodedSlashes On

<Location />
    ProxyPass https://localhost:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:8443/
</Location>
```